# Rspec allow(Class)to_receive(:class_method) not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've read [the docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/method-stubs), but it appears I still can't stub this class method from outside the class's spec.

I'm trying to stub a method called on NoteMailer

spec:

```
describe '#send_notification' do
  subject { Note.new }

  it 'sends an email' do
    expect(subject.id).to be_nil
    expect(subject).to be_valid

    # The important part
    allow(NoteMailer).to receive(:conversation_recipients).and_return(['user@dev.null'])

    note.save!
  end
end
```

note.rb

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :send_notification

  def send_notification
    NoteMailer.send_notification(self)
  end
end
```

conversation_mailer.rb

```
class NoteMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def self.send_notification(note)
    recipients = conversation_recipients(note)

    # This point is always reached, but recipients is always []
  end

  def self.conversation_recipients(note)
    []
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong with stubbing this method?

It's interesting that this same line works find when within the NoteMailer spec.

```
allow(described_class).to receive(:conversation_recipient).and_return(['user@dev.null'])
```

How can I stub the class method?

Comment: Are you sure, that your `after_commit` hook is getting called? Because if your tests are wrapped in transactions (standard rspec setup) `after_commit` hooks don't get fired out of the box.

Comment: Good point. I'm using the gem test_after_commit so after_commit is triggered.

Comment: This is strange, everything should work. If you change `allow` to `expect`, do you receive a failing expectation? You may also try to stub something up on the stack, say `NoteMailer.send_notification` method. Also, try to test without `after_commit` hook, maybe that's still the case.